# How to echo nested stdClass PHP (json encode decode)

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested, stdclass

I have the following stdclass object array :

```
var_dump($order);

array (size=2)
'raw' => 
object(stdClass)[6]
  public 'actionCodeDescription' => string 'processing.error.203' (length=20)
  public 'params' => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'respCode_desc' => string 'Transaction rejected' (length=83)
```

I'm trying to retrieve and show the '`params' {'respCode_desc : "transact rejected'}`

for example If I call for

`actionCodeDescription` I just have to `echo $order->message();`

```
    public function message()
{
    return $this->raw->actionCodeDescription;
}
```

what I have tried : `$this->raw->params['0']->respCode_desc;` It did not work
I would get

> Trying to get property 'respCode_desc' of non-object or
> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Any ideas what I'm I doing wrong

One more thing how do I check if `respCode_desc` is not empty so I can display
`actionCodeDescription` ?

Here's my code

```
class Order
{
public $raw;

function __construct($obj)
{
    $this->raw = $obj;
}
    public function __toString()
{
    return json_encode($this->raw, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Comment: "It did not work" - what does that mean? What happens instead?

Comment: I don't understand what the json_encode call at the bottom has to do with this, or the code at the top where you're converting the object to an array; but your bug is that `params` isn't an array, so there is no `params['0']`

Comment: Why `params['0']`, your var_dump indicates that `params` is a `stdClass` _object_?

Comment: Yes sorry wrong formulation it's stdClass object, I'm not looking to convert array just to fetch the specific object key value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved

```
 <?php echo $order->getCibMessage(); ?>

function getCibMessage()
{
    $obj = $this->raw;

    if (isset($obj->params) && isset($obj->params->respCode_desc)) {
        return  $obj->params->respCode_desc;
    } else {
        return $obj->actionCodeDescription;
    }
}
```